# Pass PHP generated JS objects to JS

Tags: javascript, php

I generate some JS objects strings in PHP because all of the variables i need are there, instead of passing them to js and generate the object there:

```
$results[] = "{value:" . $data . ",color:\"rgba($aa,$ab,$ac," . Config::$TRANSPARENCY_B . ")\",highlight:\"rgba($ba,$bb,$bc," . Config::$TRANSPARENCY_B . ")\",label:\"" . $entry->getDate() . "\"}";
```

Now i want to pass the finished result list of JS object strings to JS in order to display it. The resulting structure should be like: `[{object1}, {object2}, ...]`

In order to achieve this i use `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")`

However this ends up in something of the structure: `{"{object1}", "{object2}", ...]`, which of course won't work. How can i manage to throw away the useless enclosing `"`? I had a look through `json_encode()` and `htmlspecialchars()` but none of the parameters there seems to fit.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: Turns out i am completely dumb. Of course i should pack up some real objets and not a string representing them.. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create real objects, that way encoding them as JSON is easy

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->value = $data;
$obj->label = $entry->getDate();

$results[] = $obj;

echo json_encode($results);
```

Associative arrays would also be outputted as "objects" in JSON, and is probably easier

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off not manually making JSON out of strings and use the `json_encode` function to do it for you:

```
$results[] = array(
  'value' => $data,
  'color' => "rgba($aa,$ab,$ac," . Config::$TRANSPARENCY_B . ")",
  'highlight' => "rgba($ba,$bb,$bc," . Config::$TRANSPARENCY_B . ")",
  'label' => $entry->getData()
);

echo json_encode($results);
```